# How to resolve JDK issue when building Gradle projects

Tags: java

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home contains a valid JDK installation.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Use this command to see java paths: /usr/libexec/java_home -V | grep jdk

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
1.8.271.09 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
1.8.0_222 (x86_64) "AdoptOpenJDK" - "AdoptOpenJDK 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 0):

Copying tools.jar in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/` to `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/` solved the problem.